# Adding Google Fonts and Tag Manager to Content-Security-Policy using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, content-security-policy

Im looking into adding come CSP header in my htaccess file.

So far i have this working.

```
Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"
```

which is great, apart form now my google font isn't working. After some googling i found this example which works for someone else, but the problem is, it give me a 500 internal error when i go to view the site.

```
Header add Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; font-src http://fonts.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://fonts.googleapis.com
```

I would also like to add in google analytics / tag manager.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i don't fully understand CSP as of yet.